# Custom Navigation for xamarin.android

Tags: c#, layout, view, xamarin, drawer

how can I make my own navigation for a xamarin android device?

I want to have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Xamarin NavigationDrawer sample?
Maybe it will help you:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/NavigationDrawer/